# How do I get a true panels page clone?

Tags: 7, panels

Any panels experts here? I want to clone a panels page with fieldable panels panes on it. I can use the clone option in the page manager. It creates a new page at a new url but the FPP are just referencing the original. So if I change the fpp content on this page, it will change it on the original page and visa versa.

How do I get a true clone with new (editable) fpp instances?

Comment: What's FPP? and which Drupal version are you using?

Comment: Using drupal 7.50. FPP are fieldable panel panes. This is a complex question because panels, ctools, and fpp are all interrelated in the clone process.